# How to use if/then/else correctly here?

Tags: lua

How can I fix this,When run,it does not solve for A,B,C,it only outputs exactly what I enter,for example,I enter 3,B,5,it outputs 3,B,5,not 3,4,5!Please note,the trig ratio's are not complete,and I just copied them in.

```
print("Welcome to my right triangle solver")
print("What is side A?Enter A if unknown!")
A=io.read()
print("What is side B?Enter B if unknown!")
B=io.read()
print("What is side C?Enter C if unknown!")
C=io.read()
print("What is angle a?Enter a if unknown!")
a=io.read()
print("What is angle b?Enter b if unknown!")
b=io.read()
print("What is angle c?Enter c if unknown!")
c=io.read()
if A == "string" then
  A=math.sqrt(C^(2)-B^(2))
elseif B == "string" then
  B=math.sqrt(C^(2)-A^(2))
elseif C == "string" then
  C=math.sqrt(A^(2)+B^(2))
end
print("Great!")
print("Calculating")
print("Side A is=" .. A)
print("Side B is=" .. B)
print("Side C is=" .. C)
print("Side a is=" .. a)
print("Side b is=" .. b)
print("Side c is=" .. c)
print("done")
print("What is your name? ")
name=io.read()
print("Thank you," .. name)
print("How was your day?")
day=io.read()
print("mine too,bye!")
io.read()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply,and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if B == "string"
```

should be

```
if B == "B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a possible solution:

```
a = io.read()

if not tonumber(a) then
    --do stuff
end
```

Any input (even no input) that is not a number is true.

That is probably what you where trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
If A == "string" then
```

With

```
If type(A) == "string" then
```

And do that also for B and C, it should work.